# MySql Copy a row, amend value and insert each row

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 7 fields - one, `product_special_id`, being  `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

The table contains the product prices for different product groups.

So for example:

```
product_special_id: 1532 (AUTO_INCREMENT)    
product_id: 4   
customer_group_id: 3     
priority: 0      
price: 280.5000      
date_start: 0000-00-00   
date_end: 0000-00-00
```

I need to copy each record assigned to `customer_group_id` '3' to a new record in the same table with a new `customer_group_id` - lets say '5'.

The `product_special_id` for the new record must be unique. The remaining five fields remain the same.

The original record needs remain unaltered.

Can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into t(product_id, customer_group_id, priority, price, date_start, date_end)
    select product_id, 5, priority, price, date_start, date_end
    from t
    where customer_group_id = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

This query work for your issue:

```
insert into `tablename` (product_id,customer_group_id,priority,price,date_start,date_end) 
select product_id,5,priority,price,date_start,date_end from `tablename` where customer_group_id=3
```

For more information about [insert select syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) see the mysql documentation.